# How to display html link inside table cell using reactjs material-table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using material-table of Reactjs npm package, I want display a link with url inside table cells. but it is displaying it as string. Any idea how to display link

```
data: [
      {
        subject: 'Announcment',
        type: 1,
        approver: 'john',
        state: 1,
        view: "<Link to="/users">cell</Link>",
      },
    ]
```

Comment: try it `view: () => <Link to="/users">Cell</Link>`

Comment: tried no luck. also tried the following way
view: () => {return (<Link to="/users">Cell</Link>)},

It says the following error:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(TableCell)`, expected a ReactNode.

Comment: Can you give me some reference about `material-table`?

Comment: Here it is https://material-table.com/#/

Comment: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try out something like this

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const columns = [
  {
    header: '',
    id: 'links',
    render: ({ row }) => (<Link to={{ pathname: `/example/${row.id}` }}>{row.name}</Link>)
  }
];
```

I didn't double-check the code so there might be some syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

Yes Here is the solution.

```
columns: [
      { 
        title: 'Analytics', 
        field: 'analytics', 
        render: rowData => <Link to="/{rowData.url}">view</Link>,,
      },
    ],

and 


data: [
      {
        subject: 'Announcment',
        type: 1,
        approver: 'john',
        state: 1,
        url: "/users",
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const columnContent = [
    { title: 'No', render: (rowData: any) => rowData.tableData.id + 1 },
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Website',
      field: 'companyURL',
      render: (rowData: any) => (
        <a
          href={rowData.companyURL}
          target="_blank"
          style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
        >
          {rowData.companyURL}
        </a>
      ) },
  ];
          <MaterialTable
        {...other_props_here}
            columns={columnContent}
            }}
          />
```

sample column data like below

```
{
 name: "alex",
 companyURL : "https://durga.io/"
}
```